# Why is String::find not a method on &str?

Tags: string, rust, slice

I recently noticed that [`String::find`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.find) is actually a method on an owned `String`.

But I can't see why it wouldn't just be a method on `&str` instead, making it useful in more cases (and still being just as useful for `String`).  Am I missing a reason for why it's like this, or is it just a historical accident?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently, the documentation confused you. This method is listed under this section:

[image: Methods from Deref<Target=str>]

So it is not even implemented for `String`, but indeed just [for `&str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.find).

Comment: Beat me by seconds :D.

Comment: Argh, so it is.  It's hard to see that when there are so many methods, and I keep being confused by there being two doc pages for `str`, for the primitive `str` and the module.

Answer (score 5):

Actually it's only available for `String` because it `Deref`s to `str`:

```
Methods from Deref<Target=str>
```

You won't find it in [the source for String](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/collections/up/src/libcollections/string.rs.html), but in [the source for `str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/collections/up/src/libcollections/str.rs.html#749-752).

Answer (score 5):

Actually... you are wrong: it is not a `String` method.

What you are looking at is [`str::find`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/primitive.str.html#method.find).

It just so happens that the Rust documentation automatically includes on the `String` page the methods brought in by the fact that `String` implements `Deref<Target=str>` as [can be seen here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.len-1).

---

Why does the documentation includes the methods that can be called on the target of `Deref`?

Because you can actually call them directly on a `String` object, since the compiler will automatically follow `Deref` if it does not find the method you are calling, recursively.